# Macro - Moving User Specified Email to Folder

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have created small scripts before but never created an Outlook VBA before. I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction or provide a couple lines of code to get me started.

We receive email notification for tickets in a shared mailbox. The subject for the emails start with Request# XXXXXX. I want to create a macro where when you run the macro, it will prompt for the request number.

Once it locates the email, it will automatically move the email to the user's folder in the shared mailbox. Note that the name of the folder it is being moved to is the user's username.

Hope I explained it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can explore the different objects in Outlook:

```
Sub exploreItems()
'Namespace is the big picture
Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Then come the folders:
For Each fold In ns.Folders
    'If you have any subfolder:
    For Each f In fold.Folders
        'Now the mail items:
        For Each it In f.Items
            'once you arrive to the mail item, you can do anything with it
            MsgBox it.Subject
        Next it
    Next f
Next fold
End Sub
```

Since you are familiar with making scripts, check the [methods and properties of the MailItem object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320338(v=office.15).aspx) to find out what you can do with it, you can copy, move it, save, save as etc depending on what you need.